# Connecting SKOS with dspace

Tags: dspace, skos

I've installed a DSpace repository system in my server and I want to attach SKOS capabilities to my controlled-vocabularies. Does anyone know or have guidlines (step by step example) how to do this?

I also want to add the EDM metadata format to dspace but I don't have an example on how to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be including a vocabulary server with skos capbilities. Try ASKOSI  (as its name implies). We have used it for some projects and there are some good examples of Askosi-dspace integration around there: http://www.windmusic.org/dspace/.

Comment: I have tried implementing ASKOSI by following the instruction from here: http://www.destin-informatique.com/ASKOSI/Wiki.jsp?page=install but at some point there is a reference to a "memo.jar" which I dont know where to find...